# Android Authentication with SqlServer using web services

Tags: c#, android, asp.net

I am a begineer..How can i compare the values(Email & Pass) entered in texboxes of Android and compare it with the values stored in SqlServer database using webservices?

Comment: what have u done so far?

Comment: your are looking for an example?

Comment: I am looking for an example

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand what exactly you are looking for, but you want to interact with sql via php this link will help you.

```
http://android-am.blogspot.in/2012/10/android-login-screen-by-connecting-to.html
```

Comment: is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I want this in asp.net c#